# How to enable Update Management in Azure DevTest labs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I want to enable automatic patching on my Azure DevTest Lab virtual machines but I can't see **Update management** under **Operations**.

The machines are based on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and I get the hint from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-guidance-governance-application-migration-integration) that Azure Market place images are automatically patched... but I can't find a reference that actually states that...

Is there another way to enable the blade?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, When you create Azure VMs in the Azure DevTest Lab. The VMs are created in this resource group rather than in the resource group in which the lab exists. The resource group created for you with the name `<your resource group name><random numbers>`. For example: `splab3988722144001`.

To enable **Update Management** in Azure DevTest labs VMs,

Firstly, you could search **virtual machines** in the top center box of the Azure portal and filter by the lab VM name.

[image]

Secondly, click your specific Azure VM, then you will see the virtual machine overview ----operations---update management.

[image]